# How to close a tab when a form embedded in it closed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have my form embedded on top of the tabpage. When I closed the form which is on top of the tabpage, how do I also make the tabpage close as well?

The code when I put my form on the tabpage is more less like this:

```
client c = new client(car_name, owner);   //here client is another winform class
c.TopLevel = false;
c.Visible = true;
c.BackColor = Color.Ivory;
c.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
c.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
tabControl1.TabPages[tab_index].Controls.Add(c);
```

Comment: WPF?  Silverlight?  Metro?  WinForms?

Comment: From `FormBorderStyle` I'm going to guess WinForms.

Comment: @qwrqwr what type does `client` inherit from? `Form`, `UserControl`, or `Control`?

Comment: Why don't you just remove the tab at the same time you remove the form?  Subscribing the form's Disposed event is technically possible but it is risky.  You'll have a nasty leak if the tab contains any other controls.

Comment: @surfen  my client is a winform

Comment: I see, if the answer provided by AmenAyach doesn't solve your problem maybe this does: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17640/Tabbed-MDI-Child-Forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the FormClosing event :

```
private void ClientForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
      ((TabControl)((TabPage)this.Parent).Parent).TabPages.Remove((TabPage)this.Parent);
    }
```

Comment: One more question, how do the tabpage parent know if the winform closed?